# How to use only one query (no sub query) to get the rows which mach the requirement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some suggestions for my case.
First, I have a table (T1) like this:

```
         Date   ID  Flag 
   2020-08-05    a    0    
   2020-09-05    a    0
   2020-10-05    a    1
   2020-11-05    a    1 
   2020-12-05    a    0
   2020-08-05    b    1    
   2020-09-05    b    1
   2020-10-05    b    1
   2020-11-05    b    1 
   2020-12-05    b    1
   2020-08-05    c    0    
   2020-09-05    c    0
   2020-10-05    c    0
   2020-11-05    c    0 
   2020-12-05    c    0
```

I want to have a table like this:

```
         Date   ID  Flag  Result
   2020-08-05    a    0   (null)
   2020-09-05    a    0   (null)
   2020-10-05    a    1   (null)
   2020-11-05    a    1   (null)
   2020-12-05    a    0   (null)
   2020-08-05    b    1     T
   2020-09-05    b    1     T
   2020-10-05    b    1     T
   2020-11-05    b    1     T
   2020-12-05    b    1     T
   2020-08-05    c    0     F
   2020-09-05    c    0     F 
   2020-10-05    c    0     F 
   2020-11-05    c    0     F
   2020-12-05    c    0     F
```

The issue is, if I can use only one query (without any sub query), what I can do?
I tried like this:

> Select *
> case
> when Flag = 0 then 'F'
> when Flag = 1 then 'T'
> End as Result
> From T1;

But for the ID = a, if i used this query, the result is not right.
I know, i use 'With' or something else with a sub query (one moere 'select..'), the problem can be easily solved.
So, what if i can use only one 'select...', any suggestions?

Comment: Can `flag` have other values, or are they constrained to 0 and 1? Can the `flag` ever be `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want window functions to compare *all* the values for a given `id`.  The following returns 0/1 (which makes sense to me:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(flag) over (partition by id) = max(flag) over (partition by id)
             then min(flag) over (partition by id)
        end) as result
from t;
```

For Y/N:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(flag) over (partition by id) = 1 and
                  max(flag) over (partition by id) = 1
             then 'Y'
             when min(flag) over (partition by id) = 0 and
                  max(flag) over (partition by id) = 0
             then 'N'                 
        end) as result
from t;
```

Note:  This assumes that `flag` is never `NULL`, which is consistent with your data.

Comment: This also assumes the only `flag` values are 0 and 1 (also consistent with the sample data). If so, then your query can be simplified: if `min(flag)` is 1, you don't need to check `max(flag)`; and if `max(flag)` is 0, then you don't need to check `min(flag)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    create table flag_data(id varchar2(10),flag number(2));
       
    insert into flag_data values('a',0);
    insert into flag_data values('a',0);
    insert into flag_data values('a',1);
    insert into flag_data values('a',0);
    insert into flag_data values('a',1);
         
         
    insert into flag_data values('b',1);
    insert into flag_data values('b',1);
    insert into flag_data values('b',1);
    insert into flag_data values('b',1);
            
    insert into flag_data values('c',0);
    insert into flag_data values('c',0);
    insert into flag_data values('c',0);
    insert into flag_data values('c',0);
    insert into flag_data values('c',0);
    commit;
               
         
         select t.*,
           decode( min(flag) over (partition by id) - max(flag) over (partition by id),0
                 ,min(flag) over (partition by id) 
            ) as result
    from flag_data t;


select t.*,min(flag) over (partition by id) id1,max(flag) over (partition by id) id2,min(flag) over (partition by id) - max(flag) over (partition by id) minus_dta,
       decode( min(flag) over (partition by id) - max(flag) over (partition by id),0
             ,min(flag) over (partition by id) 
        ) as result
from flag_data t;
```